# NestJs, Graphql Query | Array field that can be empty

Tags: graphql, nestjs

Let's say we have the following object types

```
@ObjectType()
export class LibraryType {
  @Field(() => ID)
  id: string;

  @Field(() => [BookType])
  books: BookType[];
}

@ObjectType()
export class BookType {
  @Field(() => ID)
  id: string;

  @Field()
  name: string;
}
```

And the following resolver for library type

```
  @Query(() => [LibraryType])
  async libraries(): Promise<LibraryType[]> {
    return this.libraryService.findAll();
  }
```

Now let's assume that we know for sure that the results from the service will come out like this

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    books: []
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    books: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "beasts"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now if we query this from a graphql client with the following query

```
query {
    libraries {
        id
        books {
            id
            name
        }
    }
}
```

We get an error

````
"message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field LibraryType.books.",
            "path": [
                "libraries",
                0,
                "books"
            ],
    ```

Which obviously means that GraphQL can't have the first array empty and then the second one contain books.

how can I solve this problem?
````

Comment: in librarytype object field: books: BookType[] | null and make sure that find all returns found books or null